# SQLite create a table for each category in a table OR query inside query

Tags: sql, sqlite

My DB has a table - "cars"

It has the following columns:
manufacturer | model | price

I would like to make a query that returns a table of cars for each car manufacturer where the price is 20% lower than the average price for that manufacturer

1. I wonder if there is a way to do that without for loops
2. Would it be more efficient to create a table for each car manufacturer initially?
3. Would it be more efficient to create only one result table? and just sort it by the car manufacturer

Comment: This can be done in a single but complicated SQL-query if all results are placed in one table. But first you should try yourself and if you get stuck at a specific issue you can ask here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want SQL then use a correlated subquery:

```
select c.* from cars c
where c.price < 0.8 * (
  select avg(price) from cars
  where manufacturer = c.manufacturer
)
```

or with a join:

```
select c.* 
from cars c inner join (
  select manufacturer, avg(price) price
  from cars
  group by manufacturer
) t on t.manufacturer = c.manufacturer and c.price < 0.8 * t.price
```

or with `AVG()` window function:

```
select t.manufacturer, t.model, t.price
from (
  select *,
    avg(price) over (partition by manufacturer) avgprice
  from cars
) t
where t.price < 0.8 * t.avgprice
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a table but such a query :

```
WITH c AS
(
 SELECT manufacturer, 
        SUM(price) / 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM cars 
           WHERE manufacturer = c.manufacturer ) as avg_price
   FROM cars c
  GROUP BY manufacturer
)
SELECT c0.manufacturer, c0.price, c0.id
  FROM cars c0
  JOIN c ON c.manufacturer = c0.manufacturer
 GROUP BY c0.manufacturer, c0.price, c0.id, c.avg_price 
 HAVING c0.price <= .8 * c.avg_price;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=ee7eb13610c80da3727f8d95ca5269bb)</kbd>